# How to get image container id in graph api instagram?

Tags: facebook, post, instagram, facebook-opengraph

I need the image container id to post to post the image with the endpoint: POST [https://graph.facebook.com/{api-version}/{ig-user-](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bapi-version%7D/%7Big-user-) id}/media_publish=id_contain. why does this behavior happen?

[print explorer grath api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mhiQ.png)

```
 {
    "image_url": "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/05/21/14/19/landscape-2331416_960_720.jpg"
  }
==== Response
  {
    "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'me' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100,
      "error_subcode": 33,
      "fbtrace_id": "ANY1h6JKvBrqmFHKgC_Ag"
    }
  }
```

If anyone can help me with this I would be grateful.

Comment: You are posting to `/me`, according to your screenshot - so where is the `media_publish` endpoint part?

Comment: I'm trying to get the container id first with the endpoint shown in the print

Comment: `me?media` and `me/media` are two different things.